# jq command to replace array value with non-json value

Tags: json, templates, jinja2, jq

I need a jq command to replace array values with non-json standard values i.e. in the following json input I need to replace the "webOrigins" array values with a non-json value, which is a Jinja2 template variable replacement as per the second json block below.

**Input** (`example.json`)

```
{
   "clients": [
     {
        "clientId": "abc",
        "webOrigins": [ "/", "/api" ]
     },
     {
        "clientId": "xyz",
        "webOrigins": [ ]
     }
   ]
}
```

**Desired Output**

```
{
   "clients": [
     {
        "clientId": "abc",
        "webOrigins": {{clients.abc.webOrigins}}
     },
     {
        "clientId": "xyz",
        "webOrigins": {{clients.xyz.webOrigins}}
     }
   ]
}
```

My current attempt of shell script calling jq to loop through the input json and replace with template variable is this

```
for clientId in $(jq -r '.clients[] | .clientId' example.json)
do
  jq '(.clients[] | select(.clientId == "'${clientId}'") | .webOrigins) |= {{ clients['\'${clientId}\''].webOrigins | default([]) }}' example.json > tmp.j2; mv -f tmp.j2 example.json
done
```

But fails with the error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '{' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
(.clients[] | select(.clientId == "abc") | .webOrigins) |= {{ clients['abc'].webOrigins | default([]) }}                                                            
jq: 1 compile error
```

Of course if I add double quotes around the template variable to make the replacement variable valid json the script works but I need the value to not have quotes.

Comment: Would sth like `jq '.clients[].webOrigins = ""' file | sed 's/""/{{clients.abc.webOrigins}}/g'` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be impractical to implement a jq-only solution, but jq can certainly help, e.g. the following works in your case:

```
jq '.clients[] |= (.webOrigins = "{{clients.\(.clientId).webOrigins}}")' |
    sed '/"webOrigins":/ { s/"[{][{]/{{/; s/[}][}]"$/}}/; }'
```

Comment: I think you can omit the `[...]` around each brace in the regular expressions; `sed` can tell by context that they aren't part of a bound.

Comment: i ended up going with something like that.